# how to make common unique validation?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongoose, mean-stack

I am new in MEAN STACK web application.
I want to make common unique validation which validate on blur from field.

**Register.html**

```
<input type="email" ng-model="user.email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your Email" ng-unique="User.email" required />
<span ng-show="myForm.email.$error.unique">Email already exists</span>
```

**directive.js**

```
myapp.directive('ngUnique', ['$http', function($http) {
  return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
              elem.on('blur', function(evt) {
                    scope.$apply(function() {
                          $http({
                                method: 'POST',
                                url: '/api/checkUnique',
                                data: {
                                      dbFieldValue: elem.val(),
                                      dbField: attrs.ngUnique
                                }
                          }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                                ctrl.$setValidity('unique', data.status);
                          });
                    });
              });
        }
  }
}]);
```

**route.js**

```
 var User = require('./models/user');

  app.post('/api/checkUnique', function(req, res) {
        //console.log(req.body);
        modelNameAndFieldName = req.body.dbField.split(".");
        modelName = modelNameAndFieldName[0];
        modelFieldName = modelNameAndFieldName[1];
        modelFieldValue = req.body.dbFieldValue;

        /*modelName.count({ modelFieldName: modelFieldValue }, function(err, data) {
              if (err) {
                    res.json({ "status": false });
              } else {
                    res.json({ "status": data > 0 ? true : false });
              }
        });*/

        User.count({ email: modelFieldValue }, function(err, data) {
              if (err) {
                    res.json({ "status": false });
              } else {
                    res.json({ "status": data > 0 ? false : true });
              }
        });

  });
```

**dependencies**

```
"express"  => "version": "4.7.4",
"mongoose" => "version": "4.4.5",
"mongodb"  => "version": "2.4.9",
"OS"  => "ubuntu 14.04 lts 32bit",
"angularjs"
```

The above code run perfectly but I want to make this functionality common so that in my application I can use this with any modes and any field.

Comment: Common client side or server side? It's unclear, you did a directive you can reuse it where you want.

Comment: client side , I have to use unique validation in user ,groups ,etc from on blur field.